# A "not null" type guard resolves to "never" in the else-branch

Tags: typescript, types, type-conversion

I created a type guard which checks if the argument is exactly `null`:

```
function isNotNull<T> (arg: T): arg is Exclude<T, null> {
  return arg !== null
}
```

When I test it, the `then`-branch works correctly: it strips away the `null` from the type.

```
const value: string | null = 0 as any
if (isNotNull(value)) {
  // value is of type `string` here
}
```

However, it becomes `never` in the `else`-branch.

```
const value: string | null = 0 as any
if (isNotNull(value)) {
  // `value` is of type `string` here
} else {
  // `value` is of type `never` here
}
```

I'd like it to resolve to `null` in the `else`-branch.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is the assignment:

```
const value: string | null = 0 as any
```

The compiler knows that `value` is a constant, so it can never be null.

It doesn't get much better if you use `let`:

```
let value: string | null = 'foo';
if (isNotNull(value)) {
  // `value` is of type `string` here
} else {
  // `value` is of type `never` here
}
```

Again the typescript compiler knows that the value is not null.

But if assign something where Typescript can't infer a constant value then you will have your expected `string` in the `if` branch and `null` in the `else`:

```
function isNotNull<T> (arg: T): arg is Exclude<T, null> {
  return arg !== null
}

let value: string | null = foo();

if (isNotNull(value)) {
  // `value` is of type `string` here
} else {
  // `value` is of type `null` here
}

function foo(): string | null {
    return "foo"
}
```

Also, even this last example only works if you have the `strictNullChecks` compiler option set true. If you haven't enabled `strictNullChecks` you cannot exclude `null` from `type` and the `if` branch will be `string` which is the same as `string | null` so that leaves only `never` for the `else`.

Edit:
The reason why this doesn't work when `strictNullChecks` is off is quite interesting. In that case the types `string | null` and `string` are identical. That means `value` actually has the type `string` and `Exclude<string, null>` is simply `string` (and therefore still includes `null`), so the `else` clause is left with type `never` for `value`.

Comment: Hmm, so according to this answer it's surprisingly difficult to make TypeScript NOT infer the type of something when I want to test it, right? I thought that `as any` would make it forget everything it knows (including `let`/`const`: why wouldn't it be possible for a `const` to be null? for example: `const a = null`).

Either way, I tried your suggestion, but it doesn't work. It's still `never`: https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-hnrcng. Although I'm not entirely sure if `strict` is set to `true` on the Blitz, but I can reproduce the same locally where I have `"strict": true` in config.

Comment: Your link to stackblitz works for me. Hovering over the `value` in `value.propertyDoesntExistOnTypeNever` tells me `value` is of type `null` not `never`.

A `const` can be null: the point though is that typescript knows whether it is `null` or not. That means it can tell which code is reachable for that particular const value.

Comment: That's weird. For me, it's underlined in red and I see the error about it being `unknown`.

Comment: ...But after refreshing, it works. The `tsconfig.json` on StackBlitz is not reactive; a refresh is needed. Thanks! Now to figure out why it's not working locally for me...

Comment: Until you mention `strictNullChecks` I'm pretty sure this answer is wrong. Pasting the OP's original code into a playground with `strictNullChecks` on shows the desired behavior: [Playground](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABDAzgOTlNIA2OA8AKgHyIAUAhgE4DmAXIoQJQPU3IqICiAHhDiAAmAUyIAaRGFw5SAbwBQiRFWFQQVJG0QBCALy7J0+QF958iAhRREANwoDhDK1Rhh2AH0N5EBgAyIKTgowAE8zGGByVAwsaTI7ByYmRAUlJUCUYSooAGUoFzd4+xBhJhNEYRxMlMU0jKzYvCLEkzMRfmphRFBIWAQAlEzs7Ca2Bik8FklhGyz5dpxO7vBoeE1BhryCmkpaJ3zXGimwGaygA)

Comment: @Gerrit0 that's precisely why I said at the end that you have to have `strictNullChecks` enabled. I didn't mention it until the end because of course I have it enabled everywhere anyway so it wasn't until I'd written the rest that I checked the behaviour with it turned off to compare.

Comment: @Gerrit0 but I've added another paragraph because I think it's quite interesting that without `strictNullChecks` `Exclude<T, null>` just leaves you with `T` unchanged.

Comment: @Duncan my point was that starting with "The problem here is the assignment" is misleading at best. The problem is strictNullChecks, not the assignment.